# Importing in library definition (flow-typed/) doesn't work in flow (static type checker)

Tags: javascript, flow-typed

Importing in library defintion file (flow-typed/lib.js) doesn't seem to work correclty.

Directory structure in `flow-typed`:

```
flow-typed
   | - lib.js
   | - some-types.js
```

what doesnt work:

```
// in flow-typed/lib.js
import type {SomeTypes} from './some-types'
// use SomeTypes
// SomeTypes doesn't type check and silently fails
```

what works:

```
// in flow-typed/lib.js
type SomeTypes = {} // literally copy paste from some-type
// use SomeTypes
// works now
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `flow-typed` directly to be listed under `[libs]` in `.flowconfig`:

```
[libs]
./flow-typed/
```

[More info here.](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/wiki/Importing-And-Using-Type-Definitions)

Comment: Isn't that the default already? `By default, the flow-typed folder in your project root directory is included as a library directory.`[https://flow.org/en/docs/config/libs/]